# TypeError when trying to use Regex on Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I've been working on data cleansing at my work, but getting this error on just one month of data. I've cleansed all the data from January, February, April, and May. Not sure why this file isn't working the same way as it is literally the same set up and everything. I keep getting this error, does anyone happen to know why?

The code basically grabs data from an excel sheet and determines if it's an SSD, HDD, etc. based on the title.

ex. Title: "DISCO SOLIDO SSD 240GB"
output: "SSD"

It's worked for every other file that I've run, but one of the month's data isn't working.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "__", line 55, in <module>

df['Product_Category'] = df.apply(lambda row: 'SSD' if prod_cat_ssd.search(row.Titulo_Publicacion) else row.Product_Category, axis=1)

File "__", line 6878, in apply

return op.get_result()

File "__", line 186, in get_result

return self.apply_standard()

File "__", line 296, in apply_standard

values, self.f, axis=self.axis, dummy=dummy, labels=labels

File "pandas\_libs\reduction.pyx", line 620, in pandas._libs.reduction.compute_reduction

File "pandas\_libs\reduction.pyx", line 128, in pandas._libs.reduction.Reducer.get_result

File "C:/Users/1000266230/PycharmProjects/Excel/reg_ex.py", line 55, in <lambda>

df['Product_Category'] = df.apply(lambda row: 'SSD' if prod_cat_ssd.search(row.Titulo_Publicacion) else row.Product_Category, axis=1)

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Here's my code:

```
df['Product_Category'] = '-'
df['Product_Category'] = df['Product_Category'].apply(str)

prod_cat_ssd = re.compile(r'\bSOLIDO\b|\bSSD\b|\bSÃ³LIDO\b')
prod_cat_hdd = re.compile(r'\bDURO\b|\bRIGIDO\b|\bRÃ­GIDO\b|\bRIGIDOS\b|\bHDD\b')
prod_cat_external_ssd = re.compile(r'\b(EXTERNO|EXTREME)\b.*\b(SOLIDO|SSD|SÃ³LIDO)\b|\b(SOLIDO|SSD|SÃ³LIDO)\b.*\b(EXTERNO|EXTREME)\b')
prod_cat_external_hdd = re.compile(r'\b(EXTERNO|EXTREME)\b.*\b(DURO|RIGIDO|RIGIDOS|RÃ­GIDO|HDD)\b|\b(DURO|RIGIDO|RIGIDOS|RÃ­GIDO|HDD)\b.*\b(EXTERNO|EXTREME)\b')
df['Product_Category'] = df.apply(lambda row: 'SSD' if prod_cat_ssd.search(row.Titulo_Publicacion) else row.Product_Category, axis=1)
df['Product_Category'] = df.apply(lambda row: 'HDD' if prod_cat_hdd.search(row.Titulo_Publicacion) else row.Product_Category, axis=1)
df['Product_Category'] = df.apply(lambda row: 'External SSD' if prod_cat_external_ssd.search(row.Titulo_Publicacion) else row.Product_Category, axis=1)
df['Product_Category'] = df.apply(lambda row: 'External HDD' if prod_cat_external_hdd.search(row.Titulo_Publicacion) else row.Product_Category, axis=1)
```

**Please don't mind the Spanish words or special characters.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I would take a look at the file. As it seems that your script is breaking on the following line `df['Product_Category'] = df.apply(lambda row: 'SSD' if prod_cat_ssd.search(row.Titulo_Publicacion) else row.Product_Category, axis=1)
`. In order to further troubleshoot you can add a check for type() to see if `row` is a string or else you could force a conversion to a string using the `str()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert all the attributes in your pandas lines that aren't strings to string, e.g: `row.Product_Category` to `str(row.Product_Category)`.

Comment: Ok, I got the solution by changing row.Titulo_Publicacion to str(row.Titulo_Publicacion). Thank you so much!